# How to trace a call to a stored procedure and get feedback out of its execution?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I'm calling from asp.net and I'm adding 47 parameters mostly from values selected on drop downs and radio buttons and text boxes from a form. I also have (for some reason beyond my pay grade) some parameters that are set to Null..these are also a source of some hair pulling and I don't know if these are the problems or not.

```
Dim Parameter As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@type", "u")
Dim Parameter1 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@user", User)
Dim Parameter2 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@term", terminal)
Dim Parameter3 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@url", accesslevel)
Dim Parameter4 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@name", firstname & " " & lastname)
Dim Parameter5 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@mgr", mgr)
Dim Parameter6 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@mgrEmail", mgr)
Dim Parameter7 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@phone", mgr)
Dim Parameter8 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@title", titletitle)`

... and on and on until Parameter48...

Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("dbo.proc_vsSpacAccess", conn)
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

myCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter)
myCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter1)
myCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter2)
myCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter3)
myCommand.Parameters.Add(Parameter4)
... and on until Parameter48... and then finally I run the stored proc..

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

end of subroutine...

I run this and get nothing, no feedback, nothing. How do I know what's wrong if things aren't working? do I debug from SQL Server (**I can't change the stored procedure it's not mine to change btw**) or try to debug the stored procedure from Visual Studio?

**I REPEAT, I CANNOT CHANGE THE STORED PROCEDURE IT IS READ ONLY FOR ME..**

Comment: With no details at all it is pretty difficult to offer much in the way of help here. Apparently you have a stored proc and you are expecting some results but nothing is returned. Do you get an error message? I suspect the answer is no. That means that there is no data that meets the criteria set forth in the procedure based on the parameter values you supplied. Much more than that is going to take a lot more information from your side.

Comment: How about someone telling me the general information about "HOW" to debug stored procedure calls in .net?? why do you need specifics if your smart you can tell me some general procedures.

Comment: That's because no one here works for you and this is not the way to asking for help. If you can't provide enough data for people to answer/suggest you then consider deleting your post.

Comment: Wow. Do you always get so snarky with people who are offering to help you for free? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: who's getting snarky? I take it you don't know how to answer the question then why chime in?

Comment: Try executing the procedure with your parameter value in SSMS. Does it still return nothing? Then there is no data that meets the criteria. Try looking at the code in the procedure to see what it does. If you did get a result than the error is in your code.

Comment: I do believe you are the one getting snarky. I do happen to somewhat knowledgeable about sql server. However when your first response is you telling me that I am not helpful because I asked for details I am less inclined to help. Good luck. I truly hope you can find a solution to your issue.

Comment: I'm sure your the only person on the planet that knows the answer to my problem, so I guess I need to get on my knees ey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery won't return anything unless you explicitly catch the return value.

If you want to know how query is executing, you can view using [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

[image]

1. Set a break point right after **ExecuteNonQuery**
2. Let SQL Server Profiler run at the background
3. See the executed query

You can even copy the query from Profiler, and run it in SSMS to make sure it even works.

Comment: That gets me 1/4 of the way to something, maybe, so what your saying is that the only way I can debug further after I hit the ExecuteNonQuery is to switch my thread? over to sql server profiler and continue my debugging the call with my 47 parameters from there?

Comment: remember the stored procedure is hands off and it doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks Win that helps a lot, I need to try to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the point that when it comes to executing stored procedures, you need to design it to return some feedback. Just the fact that you have stored procedure, doesn't mean that you will have any feedback. For example (pseudo-code)

```sql
Create procedure MyProc()
Begin
    Try
       -- Do something
       -- And it happens to error here
    Catch 
       ' do nothing
    End Try
End
```

Now, this one, will never give you any info of what happened, success or failure because error is handled within

Lets look at this one now, again, pseudo-code

```sql
Create procedure MyProc(@retVal int out)
Begin
    set @retVal = -1 -- assume it failed
    Try
       -- Do something

       set @retVal = 0 -- a flag that it is success
    Catch 
       ' do nothing
    End Try

End
```

Now, with this you can go to your vb code and test

```vb
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim val as Object = myCommand.Parameters(0).Value
If CInt(val) = 0 Then
    ' success route
Else
    ' error route
End If
```

Basically, this is the example of one of the few methods how to obtain info about state of execution of your stored procedure. But again, you need to code for this.

Now, if you want to know in details, what is your SP doing while it is executing, again, you need to code for this. You can create a log table, in which you will store data that you scrape within your SP. I've seen designs where each SP had one parameter `@debug`. And, when called in debug mode, it would post logs about its execution data.

Comment: All that would be nice if I could alter the stored procedure don't you think?

Comment: @Lyle Your ability to modify SP is not something I can answer. You can use profiler whatever in a day. In the code, in the running application, you can't use profiler. You need to talk to owner of Stored Procedure to refactor it. You not going to sit in front of profiler while user using your application. But if you had some return code, in your app you could build logic handling it. Obviously, the answer is, nothing you can do in production to know if stored procedure (as is) executed successfully. Unless there is dramatic failure, such as someone dropped your procedure from DB

Comment: @Lyle And really, your question is not making sense. 47 parameters or 70, what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some advice on debugging. First run profiler when you run your application (on dev!) and grab the SQL that is generated.

Next open up SSMS and put that SQL in it and see if it generated valid sql. Sometimes you qwill find it did not. Then the problem is in how you are building the sql. If the SQL is valid, either it ran but didn't give you a return message or the problem is the proc itself or the data in the parameters.

Then open up the stored proc to see what it does; if it is inserting to a table or updating a table, check that table in the db to see if the data was inserted or updated based on teh variables you sent.   You should always have unit tests built to check the results of an action stored proc, if you do not, then write them now, so the next time you test, you know what you should see in the database as a result of running the proc.

If you did not get the action you expected, try running the proc from SSMS with the profiled data. If the data still doesn't insert or update, you may need to ask the people responsible for the proc to track down what the problem is. Likely in this case, soemthing is wrong with the particular parameters you are sending although it could bea genuiine bug of a case taht was not expected. For instance you may be sending a null for a reuired field. Not all procs are built to properly handle errors, so it may not be sending one up the chain to you.